# bash pipelines and retaining colour

Tags: bash, parsing, syntax-highlighting

I prefer `bat` over `pygmentize` as `bat` has better language support and a better all round app in my opinion. However, one thing that I would like is the ability to retain it's syntax highlighted output even through `more` or `grep` or other programs. I guess that's because `more` or other apps do not support colour, but often in Linux, when something seems not possible, I find that there is some smart trick to achieve that thing, so if I pipe `bat` output to `more` or `grep`, is there a way to retain the colour that is part of the `bat` output?

e.g. `bat ~/.bashrc | more`

```
# Get latest bat release and install
bat_releases=https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/   
content=$(wget $bat_releases -q -O -) 
firstlink=$(grep -oP 'href="/sharkdp/bat/releases/\K[^"]*_amd64\.deb' <<< "$content" | head -1)
DL=$bat_releases$firstlink
ver_and_filename=$(grep -oP 'https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/\K[^"]*\.deb' <<< "$DL")
IFS='/' read -ra my_array <<< "$ver_and_filename"
ver=${my_array[0]}
filename=${my_array[1]}
IFS='.' read -ra my_array <<< "$filename"
extension=${my_array[-1]}
extension_with_dot="."$extension
filename_no_extension=${filename%%${extension_with_dot}*}
[ ! -f /tmp/$filename ] && exe wget -P /tmp/ $DL
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/$filename
```

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19320/310674

Comment: Check the documentation of `bat` to see if it has an option to colorize output when it's writing to a pipe.

Comment: In general, programs that use fancy display features when writing to a terminal disable them by default when writing to a file or pipe. Usually you're not piping to a display program, you're piping to an application that just wants to process the raw data.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.